cheking mobil device Error: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter 'start'
I try to check user device is mobile or not
public static partial class DeviceCheck
{
    public static bool IsMobileDevice(string httpContext)
    { 
        Regex b = RegexIsMobileDeviceB();
        Regex v = RegexIsMobileDeviceV();

        return b.IsMatch(httpContext) || 
                 v.IsMatch(httpContext.AsSpan(0, 4)); //<-- Line 12
    }

    [GeneratedRegex(@"(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline, matchTimeoutMilliseconds: 1000)]
    private static partial Regex RegexIsMobileDeviceB();

    [GeneratedRegex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline, matchTimeoutMilliseconds: 1000)]
    private static partial Regex RegexIsMobileDeviceV();
}

On some device, I get this error:

URL:
/product/123/
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the
range of valid values. (Parameter 'start')
at * * * DeviceCheck.IsMobileDevice(String
httpContext) in C:\Users*\DeviceCheck.cs:line
12
at * * * Controller.Product(Int32 id, String key,
Int32 page) in C:\Users*\ProductController.cs:line
169
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext
actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor
executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
isCompleted)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
context)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker
invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
isCompleted)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker
invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
isCompleted)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
context)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker
invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
isCompleted)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
context)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
context)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
context)
at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.g__Awaited|8_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl
middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
[
{
"Key": "{OriginalFormat}",

"Value": "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request."

}
]


Please show the complete stack trace, and whether you've logged the value of httpContext on the device which fails.

@Jon-Skeet I added the full error log

Okay, so what's the value of httpContext?

user request header HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

But what's the value of it in the case where the exception is thrown? That matters more than how you obtained it.

@Jon-Skeet All errors are logged with an IP of 151.106.160.165  (About 1000 logs per hour) . And I have blocked this IP for now, but I still haven't found the problem

Maybe it is better to use try...catch inside the code

I'm not sure how many different ways I can ask for what value of httpContext is causing the problem. If you're unwilling/unable to find that out, I don't expect anyone will be able to help you.
